# covariant type T occurs in contravariant position

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I know this question has been asked before, but either the answers don't apply to this case, or I don't understand them.

Basically, why doesn't the following (simple example that recreates my problem) work ?

```
class Test[+T] {
    var list: List[T] = _
}
```

The problem I am having is that I have an object, where I want to pass in an instance of `Test[Nothing]` (the empty `Test`), and this doesn't work unless I make `Test` co-variant in `T`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Making test covariant in `T` means that `Test[A]` is a subtype of `Test[Any]` for any `A`.  So lets create a `Test`:

```
val test_string = new Test[String]
```

Now we have a `Test[String]` and the contained `list` is type `List[String]`.

Since `Test[String]` is a subtype of `Test[Any]`, the following should be allowed:

```
val test_any : Test[Any] = test_string
```

And now, we have a `Test[Any]`, and therefore `test_any.list` is type `List[Any]`, which means the following should be valid:

```
test_any.list = List[Any]()
```

Which means we just assigned a `List[Any]` to test_strings list member, which shouldn't be allowed, since that is supposed to be a `List[String]`, not a `List[Any]`.  It also means you could prepend anything at all to the list, since it is type `List[Any]`.

Comment: So how can I have my containing list vary with the type parameter of the Test class, or is that not possible?

Comment: @monkjack You could make `list` a `val`: `class Test[+T](val list: List[T])`, but this might not always be option, depending on when you initialise the list.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that works, unfortunately I'm actually json'ing this and Jackson won't unmarshall to a class constructor AFAIK. I might see if I can get away with a case class in my uses.

Comment: The specific issue here is that defining `list` as a `var` the compiler automatically provides the mutator method `def list_=(l: List[T]): Unit`, and in this method the `T` type parameter is not in *covariant* position. The same would happen if you try to set `T` as *contravariant*, because of the corresponding accessor method. There's no workaround other than setting `T` as *nonvariant* or using a `val` for your list.