# Scala covariant type error

Tags: scala

I tried to define a class

```
abstract class Sequence[+A] {
    def append (x: Sequence[A]): Sequence[A]
}
```

and got in the terminal

```
<console>:8: error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type Sequence[A] of value x
           def append (x: Sequence[A]): Sequence[A]
```

Why isn't this definition OK and what would be the best way to fix this? 
I checked this [covariant type T occurs in contravariant position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584830/covariant-type-t-occurs-in-contravariant-position) but nothing helpful for me there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
abstract class Sequence[+A]{
  def append[B >: A](x: Sequence[B]): Sequence[B]
}
```

When you define a covariant type you can't use it as an input parameter (you would have the same problem with a contravariant type used for a returned type). The workaround is to define a new type (here B) that is a super type of A.

Answer (score 7):

As usual given his expertise in Scala, @vptheron is exactly right on the solution. But let me add a little to the "why" with an example inspired by Scala author Martin Odersky himself.

By defining `Sequence[+A]`, you're saying if `B` is a subtype of `A`, then `Sequence[B]` is a subtype of `Sequence[A]`.

I think type stuff makes a lot more sense when you take it out of the abstract (no pun intended) and use a concrete example.

Let's create a concrete implementation:

```
class IntSequence extends Sequence[Int] {
  override def append(x: Sequence[Int]) = {
    println(math.sqrt(x.head))
    //makes no sense but humor me
  }
}
```

Covariance in `A` means that because `Int` is a subtype of `Any`, `Sequence[Int]` is a subtype of `Sequence[Any]`. So far so good.

Now imagine a concrete class `StringSequence` defined in a similar way to `IntSequence`.

Then let's do this:

```
val x:Sequence[Any] = new IntSequence
val ss:Sequence[Any] = new StringSequence
//Let ss be populated somehow
x.append(ss)
```

The first line is valid of course. `IntSequence` is a subclass of `Sequence[Int]`, and `Sequence[Int]` is a subtype of `Sequence[Any]` by covariance.

The second line is valid of course. For a similar reason.

The third line (the line after the comment) is valid of course. `Sequence[String]` is a subclass of `Sequence[Any]`, so I can append a `Sequence[String]` to a `Sequence[Any]`.

But when I try the two lines together, I have now said that I can take the square root of the first element of my `Sequence[String]` because `x` is really a `IntSequence`.

To borrow a line from the American movie Apollo 13, "Houston, we have a problem."

This is why you get that error. To generalize, *as soon as a generic parameter appears as the type of a parameter to a method, the class that contains that method can't be covariant in that type* because you get exactly that kind of weirdness.

To get around this, you need a lower bound for the type parameter in the method definition. In other words, the type in the method parameter must be a supertype of the covariant type in the class definition.

Or more simply, do what @vptheron does.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great explanation! I was a bit lazy on this one :)

Comment: Thanks! No worries. There are others who need your Super Scala heroism.